# What does the DEVICE field stand for in lsof?

Tags: lsof

Here is an abridged output of lsof -i tcp:XXXXXX:

```
COMMAND PID  USER FD TYPE DEVICE
python3 9336 root 3u IPv4 3545328
python3 9336 root 5u IPv4 3545374
```

Comment: Please check the [man page for lsof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) and clarify which part you don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ man 8 lsof | grep -A 10 '^\s\{7\}DEVICE'
   DEVICE     contains the device numbers, separated by commas, for a character special, block special, regular, directory or NFS file;

              or ``memory'' for a memory file system node under Tru64 UNIX;

              or the address of the private data area of a Solaris socket stream;

              or a kernel reference address that identifies the file (The kernel reference address may be used for FIFO's, for example.);

              or the base address or device name of a Linux AX.25 socket device.

              Usually only the lower thirty two bits of Tru64 UNIX kernel addresses are displayed.
```

Or type

`man 8 lsof`

Inside man you can search with `/`. Than type directley without space a regex. In your case `^\s*DEVICE` and you will jump to `DEVICE`.

Comment: Boy, god knows you don't have to be like that.